# Bigcommerce Stencil access more subcategory levels on category page

Tags: bigcommerce

Is there any way to access more subcategory levels on the category page? Currently, in the context of the `category` on a category page, there exists a `subcategories` attribute which lists the immediate children of the current category. Is there any way to have the system return the subcategories of each of those subcategories as well?

I was hoping this could be done via front-matter or some setting in the control panel?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a way with the existing front-matter or store settings. It would need to be added by BigCommerce as a new feature.

Answer (score 0):

Been there! And as answered be Alyss there's no way to do that straight from the server.

That being said you can always get it done through an AJAX call to the subcategory url and take just what you need from there to finish populating your category page with subcategory products.

First in the category template file I added an empty element with the data I needed to make the call:

```
<div class="nested container">
    <main data-ajax-url="{{url}}" class="product-listing-container"></main>
</div>
```

Then I added this method to the theme/category.js file and called it inside the loaded method called on template load.

```
getSubcategoryProducts() {
    $('[data-ajax-url]').each((index, el) => {
        const $this = $(el);
        const thisCatURL = $this.data('ajax-url');
        let $thisCatProducts;

        $.ajax({
            url: thisCatURL,
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'html',
            async: true,

        }).done((data) => {
            $thisCatProducts = $(data).find('#product-listing-container').html();

            $this.html(thisCatProducts);
        });
    });
}
```

I'm sure there are better ways to do it, probably through the Stencil Utils API but I'm still trying to get a grasp of it as there's close to zero documentation on that.

Good coding!